# How to identify AudioStreamer isBuffering state or As_Waiting_for_queue_to_start state?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, audio-streaming, audiostreamer

Continue from [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453076/while-using-next-and-previous-functionality-in-audiostreamer-two-or-more-songs-s)
I found that when I am having slow streaming from internet and I click next and Previous buttons then two or more song starts because when a new instance of AudioStreamer is created and State of AudioStreamer is neither of isPause, isIdle or isStop.

But actually a new Thread starts inside AudioStreamer class and has isBuffering or As_WAITING_FOR_QUEUE_TO_START state.

My question is how can i identify this states so that when I click Next button twice then only 1 song starts and other request is rejected?

Please help in this regards.. thanx

Comment: This is very generalized question considering that you have not posted what code you are using and how you are implementing AudioStreamer in your code.

Comment: please go through the link given with previous question which includes code..

Comment: Ok got it. But do delete the previous question and bring the code in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual problem i was having is when my song is being stream and i click next then 2 songs started toghther.

So I found that this is a bug in AudioStreamer Class and the solution to this could be something as [link given on gitHub](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer/issues/26)